# Is there a contradiction between open access/science positions adopted at many universities and their reliance on Google services?

Tags: open-access, open-science

I work at a faculty which is completely dedicated to open access and open science. They do everything in accordance with best practices. Very cool.

But at the same time they are totally embedded in the Google infrastructure, using Gmail, Calendar, Drive and so on. Even I, a Google skeptic, find myself using it because it’s so gosh dang easy.

I’ve been recently invited to join the Open Access Committee, which is obviously terrific. I think of taking up this issue, but I can’t really get a grip on the extent to which this may be a totally different issue, or a related one. Therefore I’d like to hear your advice on the matter!

Comment: What exactly is your concern about Google's infrastructure here? The main issue people have with Google usually is privacy, but that's not a concern if your data has to be 'open' anyway.

Comment: Open science and open source may share some principles, but they are very different things with very different goals. You should add to your question why you feel the two things are in contrast with each other.

Comment: I suppose the university could just stop using those services and leave it up to everyone to find their own. Or spend more money to set up something remotely similar. Not all services are free (and universities pay Google for them).

Comment: Could you possibly point at a statement of what is meant by "open access" and "open science"? I have heard several different definitions of each.

Comment: @Andrea The OP never mentioned "open source"?

Comment: VtC as needing detail as to what you think is in conflict. Remember, the vast majority of scientists are not hacker nerds that are excited to host their own email servers and pass things around with `scp`.

Comment: I’m not a “hacker nerd” either and I’m def not suggesting that anyone host their own email servers. Not sure what gave you that impression.

Comment: @Teusz Sorry - sometimes people on this site offer extremely techie solutions to things, forgetting that not everyone in academia is in CS/math and excited about LaTeX/hosting their own Discord clone/having students upload files to somewhere outside the LMS/etc... That said, since you didn't really explain your objections, there wasn't a lot to go on.

Answer (score 20):

Its a totally seperate issue.

Other than closed  science = bad, large monopolistic tech company = bad, I not sure I see any connection.

Open Science/Open Access is about publishing all your data and methods in fora that allow free access to everyone as soon as possible. Is there anything specifically about google that prevents or makes this harder?

I can't think of anything.

Comment: Indeed. It isn't like Outlook would be any better/different.

Comment: @JonCuster, hmmm, Outlook could be and is worse. Much worse. Much much ..... worse.

Comment: @Buffy - as a user experience, sure. Perhaps even from a university IT perspective, but in terms of supplying email and collaborative spaces Microsoft does OK. My institution does just fine with them, but has no option to use Google.

Comment: @Buffy At least for Outlook an institution can set it up to not read the contents of all your emails. For Gmail, that's not possible, so it's impossible to use any Google services when you deal with HIPAA-protected anything, for example (not that it's great to transmit any PII via email anyways, but even tiny bites of information can be HIPAA protected, like emailing a research participant about a scheduled appointment).

Comment: @BryanKrause Can't an institution make the (paid?) Google Workspace version HIPAA-compliant? https://support.google.com/a/answer/3407054

Comment: Outlook not only reads and filters all my email, any link I click in an email is filtered through MS servers before it is sent. This is advertised as a "security" feature. My outgoing email is also filtered. (We know who you are. We know who you talk to. We even know what you read.) Yes, I know that my institution is one of the sinners here.

Comment: @Anyon Ah, maybe they can now! Guess I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't think of anything? Ask your librarians, always!
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_ny6hxY46M1i2eML3-uzePfmeY7vi3lio9vOp755Fig/edit#slide=id.gce900bb84f_0_41

There is a reason why Google is so successful commercially ... they do things you can't think of!

Comment: @earlgrey So Google provides a service that isn't perfect for sharing OA manuscripts. I'm not sure u see this as being actively harmful to OA. It doesn't prevent a GApps  shop from using other services. At worst it provides a substandard service where those without a Google drive have no service. The original post seems to concentrate on Gmail, goal etc  which seems unconnected.

Comment: This is such an incredibly naive question, I'm glad it was asked. I find many in academia don't trust their IT support/software dev support and come on here and end up asking questions like this one. The Google services listed aren't going anywhere because so many organizations and businesses rely on them. Sure Google has retired services, but that's because they weren't making money or were not actively used. The argument that Google could suddenly retire said services could be said of any vendor/third-party service.

Comment: @IanSudbery again, *The original post seems to concentrate on Gmail, goal etc which seems unconnected.", that's the reason google is so succesful. I am not arguing they are connected. At the very minimum, if you access google drive while logged in your gmail (personal or corporate) account, it is still data mining from google. Are you interested in people accessing a paper on the Uighur community discrimination? the day that Alphabet will be bought by chinese government you will regret that. 
I am arguing that the open access movement should care also about "fringe" themes.

Comment: @EarlGrey I'm not arguing that there aren't big problems with Google. I'm saying those problems are unconnected to OA/OpenScience. . Apart from anything else the problems remain even if you are not into open science.

Comment: @EarlGrey. That said,  i dont see any of the alternatives being any better. At least in Europe,  legal limitations mean that data is stored in European servers,  subject to European data protection law,  and isn't data mined, and if it were that would be both a breach of contract and law. Obviously the law wouldn't allow institutions to continue to contract Google if alphabet were bought by someone that couldn't be trusted to up hold the law.

Comment: @IanSudbery obviously, it is non-sense to put your service in such an expensive locked in risk. And still we do that, without arguing because no alternatives are any better (of course there are none, if alternatives are not discussed, possible future issues are not foreseen and things are seen in tight compartments instead of in a general framework... it is even easier than actively suppress any alternative development)

Comment: @IanSudbery who said european institutions are so smart? see the numerous instances where google has been fined, one of the most visible is this one 
https://edition.cnn.com/2019/07/22/tech/google-street-view-privacy-lawsuit-settlement/index.html

Comment: @EarlGrey Completely different - Google being fined because it turns out one of its standard services breaking GDPR is comlpetely different Google delibrately breaking a specifically drawn up service agreement with a large customer to store data on a EU server, and not harvest data from it. Apart from anything else, being found breaking those would be bad for business, but those you quote above don't really harm their bottom line. 

Yes, google are evil, supporting them is generally bad, but what has this got to do with Open Science?

Comment: @EarlGrey With lock in, its not just that google isn't any better than any others, but I see no possiblity for a system that isn't locked in. Migrating away from any email, calander or storage service is always going to be difficult, irrepsective of the service or its provider. The only problem I can see is if google becomes the defacto server of academic literature. But I see no sign of that happening. No one I know uses google scholar for searching or google's service for author manuscript (which I'd never even heard of).

Answer (score 4):

While the main concern against Google (privacy) does not apply here, there are some avenues in which the big G can cause damage. Having a good, almost-free-but-not-really service discourages the development and use of free (as in freedom) alternatives; but then this lack of openness can later become problematic because of lock-in, or because a previously-free service becomes expensive to use or is discontinued.

Examples: data is hosted on Google sites, or on Google Docs in a proprietary format; suppose Google pulls a Geocities and closes that service; then the data disappears or becomes difficult to migrate. Large datasets are hosted on Google drive, but then the user runs out of space in their free tier and decides to delete them.

[EDIT: very relevant real-life example: we just got word that the free Google Drive tier that Google offers to our university will be reduced from "unlimited storage" to "100 TB for the whole institution", so the university has until January to free up 372 TB of extra used space, or upgrade to a paid plan.]

The real problem, though, is that open alternatives are difficult to set up and expensive to maintain, while Google's stuff is free (at first) and easy to use. Becoming Google-free requires investment, and not all universities are prepared to make it. A positive example is Germany, which in the past years [has pushed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/160716/what-is-the-status-of-foreign-cloud-apps-in-german-universities) for free self-hosted services in all universities at the nation level. But this is not a simple road to take.

Answer (score -4):

Absolutely yes.

Nowadays, Google is just the offspring of a big advertising conglomerate (let's call it Alpha, because it is the alpha character in the room and not anymore a bet).

As such, Google will try to integrate and inglobate everything. See google Scholar, which is being the reference tool to find paper and citations. A part from the data collection-harvesting, its algorithms are absolutely obscure and unclear, so there is no way to evaluate why the results of certain search appears the way it appears.

So you are well in time for setting the boundary, and raise awareness of the potential pitfalls in integrating too much of the university software ecosystem in the big colossus.

For example: they are even trying to make you upload open access papers to their platform, which [then will be accessible then only via google drive (see slide 8)](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_ny6hxY46M1i2eML3-uzePfmeY7vi3lio9vOp755Fig/edit#slide=id.gce900bb84f_0_5), bypassing whatever publisher and allwing them to collect even more data without a clear consent from your side (well, you gave it long time ago, not that you had an alternative ...) !

Comment: There are certainly gripes to be had with Google, but which of those you listed are actually in tension with an institution engaging in open access and open science?

Comment: @Anyon ask your librarians!